# How to get the post url once the form is filled using php where it shows i and title in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Hi how can I get the latest post url using php mysql where it contains id and title. Am able to get the latest url through but how can I get through id and title

Comment: question is not clear please provide your code or more details

Comment: @SarangaR if I submit post1 then how I get the url of the post1 on screen like example.com/1/post1 I want to get the latest by id